# Tailwind global variables forcig my tailwind project to execute

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I was following the JSMastery YouTube tutorials and copied his globals.css from his repo but has issues on my side. I don't know what problem exactly it is, but my Next.Js project ain't running
**Here is the error I am getting**

The `font-inter` class does not exist. If `font-inter` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

```
.black_btn {
   @apply rounded-full border border-black bg-black py-1.5 px-5 text-white transition-all hover:bg-white hover:text-black text-center text-sm font-inter flex items-center justify-center;
```

I literary have no idea because I have never worked with tailwind and NextJs before, but on his side(I mean the guy leading the tutorial) is working and so I expected mine to work as well.

Comment: font-inter would be a custom class, and you need to define a path to the "inter" font. Can you also post your tailwind config, and your css file that contains your @tailwind directives?

Answer (score 0):

There must be a file named as `tailwind.config.js` if its not there create it with the following content.

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ]
}
```

Another file named as `postcss.config.js` with the following content.

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

and finally under the folder styles you should have `global.css` and this file should be imported to the main `layout.js` in the App Router like `import '../styles/global.css'` and contain something similar to this...

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components{
    .blog {
        @apply prose prose-slate prose-2xl prose-headings:underline-offset-2 mt-4 prose-li:text-lg prose-ul:list-disc prose-img:rounded-lg prose-img:w-1/2 prose-p:indent-5 prose-a:text-blue-500 prose-p:text-black prose-p:text-lg prose-headings:underline;
    }
}

@layer base {
    .font-outline-2 {
      -webkit-text-stroke: 2px black;
    }
    .font-outline-4 {
      -webkit-text-stroke: 4px black;
    }
  }
```